# VS 2017: Publish not working for one project

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, publish

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET Core 1.1.1 application to local filesystem.
I've two solutions (two different app) and for one solution the publish works fine while for the second solution, when I click publish button, nothing happens. The publish profile is the same, only site urls are different.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you have permissions to write to that folder?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it turned out the SDK version in global.json file was not updated. I am currently on SDK 2.0.3 and the version in global.json was 1.x.x. After updating the version to 2.0.0 the publish button worked fine.

```
{
  "sdk": { "version": "2.0.0" }
}
```

Comment: where is located the global.json file? I'm having the same problem but I don't see a global.json file anywhere